# Communicate with a device with an IP set to a broadcast address

Tags: ip, ip-camera, broadcast

I have a wireless IP camera that I am setting up to use for Timelapse purposes.

When configuring a static IP selected 192.168.0.255 so as to be memorable, I latter found out (after I couldn't connect to the device) that this is a broadcast address and as a result I have not been able to communicate with the device.

What can I do to regain connection so I can set a new IP, there is no hardware reset button.

Other details

- Router IP 192.168.0.1
- Subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: I follow the video to help me set my camera software IP address to communicate with device: http://youtu.be/dciRwIZhLwQ

Answer (score 4):

If you set your IP address to `192.168.0.2 subnet mask 255.255.0.0`, when your PC tries to communicate with the router, it won't matter that the router address is 192.168.0.255 because from your PC's perspective, the broadcast address is `192.168.255.255`.

So packets going to the router should be fine.  The router will respond to `192.168.0.2` which it thinks is part of its local network, and so will send them direct (it has no awareness of your subnet mask).

If you try and ping it, and it doesn't reply, it may be because it won't respond to an arp request on the broadcast address.  If so, then  you can confirm this by doing this on your PC:

```
arp -a
```

If this doesn't have an entry for 192.168.0.255, then you can add one:

```
arp -s 192.168.0.255 mac_address_of_router
```

The MAC address should be on a label on the router, and you enter it in the format `00-10-54-CA-E1-40`.

Comment: I am still unable to ping the device, before setting up the arp thing I got an error of `Reply from 192.168.0.5: Destination host unreachable.` after setting the arp (via netsh) I get timeout errors. Any other suggestions, would it be easier to plug directly between laptop and camera?

Comment: What is 192.168.0.5?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned I set the computers IP to 192.168.0.5 instead of 192.168.0.2 as that IP is already taken.

Comment: That means it didn't get an arp response.  If you are confident you set the static arp entry correctly, you may have to resort to factory reset as suggested by YetiFiasco

Answer (score 1):

There must be a way to **factory reset** the device (if there is no dedicated switch, it can usually be done by pressing a **combination of buttons on power-up** or shorting specific contacts on the circuit board), I suggest reading the manual (or finding it online) and seeing how to do a factory reset.

As far as I am aware, there is **no way** to connect to the device with an invalid IP address over network, it would be like trying to post a letter without knowing the address.

If you're unable to find the manual or the manual does not specify how to reset the device, I suggest a *thorough googling*, someone has probably had the same problem and found a way to factory reset the device.

For future reference, giving the make and model of the device in question will make answering much easier.

Comment: Like I said it is a cheap camera its model number is P6-HM6020R-HL I can't find much info and the primitive manual that came with only mentions a software reset